# No onNavigationItemSelected implemtation with latest Kotlin Navigation Drawer Activity Template

Tags: templates, kotlin, navigation-drawer, android-studio-4.0

I've just created a new project in Android studio 4.0 using the "Activity Drawer Activity Template". A main activity controller and three fragments are created by the template. 
The app starts on the "Home" fragment. Menu item clicks navigate to the different fragments.
I've searched the project and cannot find any implementation of onNavigationItemSelected or other listeners.

Where the menu selections are being handled?

Here's the code from the MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow), drawerLayout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the top you need to write it like this

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
```

Once you have written it like this, you should be able to override the `onNavigationItemSelected` function.